# Apache Cayenne ROP Server "No session associated with request." on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, hessian, apache-cayenne

I develop a cayenne project with a java rich client and an remote obejct persistence server. If i the rich cient connects with a Cayenne-ROP-Server that is deployed on the same machine on localhost (on Jetty from maven goal like explained inside the cayenne rop tutorial) everythings fine:

```
ClientConnection clientConnection = new HessianConnection("http://localhost:8080/rop.server   /cayenne-service",
            "cayenne-user", "secret", SHARED_CAYENNE_SESSION_NAME);
DataChannel channel = new ClientChannel(clientConnection);
ObjectContext context = new CayenneContext(channel);
List<Object> someEntities = context.performQuery(allMovies);
```

If i change the url that i want to connect to in the first line to a non local host (Tomcat7 on ubuntu) then everything works till it comes to the 4th line:

```
List<Object> someEntities = context.performQuery(allMovies);
```

Then i get the Error "No session associated with request"

Here is the full Output of the Client:

```
Running de.pss.hdlist.client.dataservice.MovieDataServiceCayenneImplTest
Sep 07, 2012 10:21:37 AM org.apache.cayenne.remote.hessian.HessianConnection connect
INFO: Connecting to [cayenne-user:*******@http://comunity-server.hopto.org:8080    /rop.server-3.0.2/cayenne-service] - shared session 'global-cayenne-session'
Sep 07, 2012 10:21:40 AM org.apache.cayenne.remote.hessian.HessianConnection connect
INFO: === Connected, session:  org.apache.cayenne.remote.RemoteSession@12241e[sessionId=C47DD36ACE2A043401C8D0C44D5BD8C3,n    ame=global-cayenne-session] - took 3182 ms.
Sep 07, 2012 10:21:53 AM org.apache.cayenne.remote.BaseConnection sendMessage
INFO: --- Message 0: Bootstrap
Sep 07, 2012 10:21:53 AM org.apache.cayenne.remote.BaseConnection sendMessage
INFO: === Message 0: Bootstrap done - took 406 ms.
Sep 07, 2012 10:21:53 AM org.apache.cayenne.remote.BaseConnection sendMessage
INFO: --- Message 1: Query
Sep 07, 2012 10:21:53 AM org.apache.cayenne.remote.BaseConnection sendMessage
INFO: *** Message error for 1: Query - took 187 ms.
```

Here is the Serverside output of the Apache Tomcat log:

```
WARNING: org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.MissingSessionException: [v.3.0.2 Jun 19 2011 09:29:50] No session associated with request.
org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.MissingSessionException: [v.3.0.2 Jun 19 2011 09:29:50] No session associated with request.
    at    org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.BaseRemoteService.processMessage(BaseRemoteService.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:180)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:109)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianServlet.service(HessianServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I use Apache Cayenne 3.0.2, Apache-Tomcat 7.0.29 and Java 7 sdk

THX in advance for every Help

PS. Maybe the local Jetty server handles things in another way as the Tomcat Server on remote unix machine.

Edit:
After the hint given by Andrus in the answer below i added an SessionListern that looks like this:

```
public class HttpSessionListenerLogImpl implements HttpSessionListener {

private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HttpSessionListenerLogImpl.class.getName());

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
            "!__Session created with ID: " + hse.getSession().getId());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session created by: " + hse.getSource());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session Attributes: " + hse.getSession().getAttributeNames());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session max inactivity: " + hse.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session context: " + hse.getSession().getServletContext().getServletContextName());
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session killed with ID: " + hse.getSession().getId());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session killed by: " + hse.getSource());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session Attributes: " + hse.getSession().getAttributeNames());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session max inactivity: " + hse.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval());
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "!__Session context: " + hse.getSession().getServletContext().getServletContextName());
}
```

So this listern gives me the following output when executing the 4 lines of code statet on top of this Question:

```
Sep 11, 2012 11:06:27 AM de.pss.hdlist.HttpSessionListenerLogImpl sessionCreated
SEVERE: !__Session created with ID: B07648A2A5F0005AF6DF0741D7EF2D21
Sep 11, 2012 11:06:27 AM de.pss.hdlist.HttpSessionListenerLogImpl sessionCreated
SEVERE: !__Session created by: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@515f9553
Sep 11, 2012 11:06:27 AM de.pss.hdlist.HttpSessionListenerLogImpl sessionCreated
SEVERE: !__Session Attributes: java.util.Collections$2@5a44a5e1
Sep 11, 2012 11:06:27 AM de.pss.hdlist.HttpSessionListenerLogImpl sessionCreated
SEVERE: !__Session max inactivity: 216000
Sep 11, 2012 11:06:27 AM de.pss.hdlist.HttpSessionListenerLogImpl sessionCreated
SEVERE: !__Session context: Cayenne Tutorial
Sep 11, 2012 11:06:27 AM com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton invoke
WARNING: org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.MissingSessionException: [v.3.0.2 Jun 19 2011 09:29:50] No session associated with request.
org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.MissingSessionException: [v.3.0.2 Jun 19 2011 09:29:50] No session associated with request.
    at  org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.BaseRemoteService.processMessage(BaseRemoteService.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at  
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:180)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:109)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianServlet.service(HessianServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Here you can see there is a session that gets created and there is no session that gets killed. So why does the ObjectContext from my line of code

```
List<Object> someEntities = context.performQuery(allMovies);
```

does ignore the session. Do i have to set it explicitly before doing a query? What is the standard initializing code on the client side to access an remotly deployed cayenne server. Does it differ from the one given inside the cayenne rop tutorial?

THX in advance.

Edit:
I upgraded to cayenne 3.1B1 hoping to get rid of this error, but same Situation here: "No session..." when trying to send a query.

I also setup a tomcat on localhost and configured it the same as the remote is. Same Problem here "No Session..." when trying to send a query.

So the Jetty on localhost is the only one that takes the 4 line init code from above and holds the session for every following query. So here is my Question. Does anyone on this planet ever tried to deploy a cayenne rop server on a tomcat and succeeded?

THX in advance for every little hint.

Edit:
So i did a litte bit of server side debugging on my local tomcat7.

1.Client executes line 2 of code from above:

```
DataChannel channel = new ClientChannel(clientConnection);
```

on the Serverside my session listener gets triggerd and tells me a session has been created with id: B6565298F222294F601B76333DBE4911

2.Client executes line 3 from above:

```
ObjectContext context = new CayenneContext(channel);
```

On the server side the method of class org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.HttpRemoteSession gets called:

```
/**
 * Returns a ServerSession object that represents Cayenne-related state associated
 * with the current session. If ServerSession hasn't been previously saved, returns
 * null.
 */
@Override
protected ServerSession getServerSession() {
    HttpSession httpSession = getSession(true);
    return (ServerSession) httpSession.getAttribute(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

a new session gets created by line one of this method. Its ID is: ECC4A81D6240A1D04DA0A646200C4CE6. This new Session contains exactly one attribute: the key is "org.apache.cayenne.remote.service.HttpRemoteService.ServerSession" and the value is (who guessed it?) the session created before in step 1
What makes me wonder is that my serveltListener dont gets triggerd though a new session gets created.

3.Client executes line 4 from above

```
List<Object> someEntities = context.performQuery(allMovies);
```

at the serverside now the getServerSession() method is called again. This time also a new session gets created (why?). And this session does not contain any attribute. So the line "return (ServerSession) httpSession.getAttribute(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);" inside the method getServerSession() returns null and exactly this triggers the exception "No Session associated with request".

So why is the cayenne serverside creating e ne session and doesnt use the old one created befor? Do i have to explicitly send the session within the query?

Edit:
I made screenshots from the netbeans http-monitor while running the four lines of code from above:
[image: http monitor tomcat cayenne]

Comment: Please do not tag this with `Apache`, which is reserved for the Apache HTTP server.

Comment: Sorry for that, but i am a relative noob to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue between Cayenne ROP and newer containers:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAY-1739

Here is a Tomcat solution - create context.xml file with the following contents, and place it in META-INF/ of your webapp:

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator"
        changeSessionIdOnAuthentication="false" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote: "The simplest way is to create a custom javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener, put it in web.xml and make it log every session creation and destruction event with session IDs included in the log. Then you will see what happens to your sessions" Since i am new to the serverside i dont know how to achive that. Can you provide sample code or a link to a example please.

Comment: THX for your helpful reply. I added the listener you described. Look at my edited Question. I added the log output.

Comment: I also tried to upgrade to version 3.1B1 see above edited question.

Comment: I also setup a tomcat on localhost, same problem here. See edited question above

Comment: So i did a little bit of server side debugging. See my edited question above.

Comment: just added a note on Tomcat cookies. Either there's a bug in Cayenne HessianConnection/HessianProxy factory in regards to Tomcat 7 cookie policies, or there's a special configuration of cookies in your server.

Comment: Thanx for your hint. There is no special tomcat cookie config. Everythings default. I will try to debug the jetty and the tomcat to determine the difference. It would also be helpfull if you would debug the serverside on a tomcat since i dont know how it all works together.

Comment: I added screenshots from the netbeans http-monitor showing the relevant http-data.

Comment: Just rewrote the answer. This is an issue between ROP and the newer containers. We are working on it. and there is a workaround while you are evaluating ROP.

Comment: Many thanx for your work. At least i know the problem now. I would have voted your Answer up, but my reputation score is not high enough. I will vote your answer up when have the score. THX again for your work.

Comment: Actually I just added a working Tomcat solution (cloned it from the Cayenne bug report, so that it is preserved here for the record).